# Can I use the same below feature for the Json Api request aswell

Tags: karate

```
Xmlsample.feature
Feature: test A

Scenario:  test apple
    * table test_apple_one

    | payload_file              |
    | 'sample/ball.xml'         |
* def result = call read('classpath:........./samplereq.feature')  test_apple_one       



    Jsonsample.feature
Feature: test B

Scenario:  test Mango
    * table test_Mango_one

    | payload_file              |
    | 'sample/cat.`enter code here`json'         |



samplereq.feature

Feature: sample

  Background:
#Common Config load  
* def sampleURL = baseURL+'/sample/test'      
* xml payload = read('classpath:.....'+payload_file)   
#OAuth Signature generator
* def authorization = "oauth string"

  Scenario: Make the sample API call
Given url sampleURL`enter code here`
Given header Authorization = authorization
Given request payload
And header Content-Type = 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8'
And header Host = host
And header Accept = content_type
When method post    
Then match header Content-Type contains 'application/xml'
```

I am using the above feature samplereq.feature for the XML  API request and 
I Want to keep this feature samplereq.feature  as generic and use the same for the Json Api request.can I  do the same with JSON(Jsonsample.feature) API request ,please suggest

Comment: done their..any update on the above question ???

Comment: One more thing is their any way to call JS function (which returns value )in to our feature file ...I have seen only this "karate.call(fileName, [arg]) " or def result = (responseStatus == 404 ? {} : karate.call('delete-user.feature')) which calls only feature file.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question multiple times and I am sorry I can't understand what you are trying to do at all. Also I think you have not understood Karate properly. So please listen to my suggestion and take it in the right spirit.

I think you are trying to un-necessarily complicate your test. My sincere suggestion is - please don't try for this extreme re-use. I have observed that when teams attempt to create a super-generic re-usable test script - it just complicates things and becomes hard to maintain.

So please use different feature files for JSON and XML. For each test you can have multiple scenarios. Now, the scenario data can be the same for JSON and XML and you can read a common JSON file. Refer to this example on how you can create XML out of JSON: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature

If you still insist on the JSON and XML both in a generic feature, please take a look at this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/loopcall

The above also has an example of calling a JavaScript function. Also please read the docs carefully.